# How to decode audio via FFmpeg in Android

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, decode

I am writing a player for Android with FFmpeg compiled for Android NDK.

I could open the file through FFmpeg and wrote this:

```
av_register_all();

char* str = (*env) -> GetStringUTFChars(env, argv, 0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "HelloNDK!", str, str);

if (av_open_input_file (&pFormatCtx, str, NULL, 0, NULL) != 0)
    return -2; // Couldn't open file

// Retrieve stream information
if (av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx) < 0)
    return -3; // Couldn't find stream information

// Dump information about file onto standard error
dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv, 0);

// Find the first video stream
videoStream =- 1;
audioStream =- 1;
for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO && audioStream <0) {
        audioStream = i;
    }
}

if (audioStream == -1)
    return -5;

aCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;
// Set audio settings from codec info

aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(aCodecCtx->codec_id);

if (!aCodec) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unsupported codec! \n");
    return -1;
}

avcodec_open (aCodecCtx, aCodec);
```

How can I now decode the audio and return it to the Java program? Maybe somebody could give me an example

EDIT:
When using avcodec_decode_audio3 
Get the following: 

03-22 07:54:00.988: INFO / DEBUG (31): *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *** *** * ** *****  ** *** 
03-22 07:54:00.988: INFO / DEBUG (31): Build fingerprint: 'generic / sdk / generic /: 2.2/FRF91/43546: eng / test-keys' 
03-22 07:54:00.988: INFO / DEBUG (31): pid: 435, tid: 435>>> org.libsdl.app <<< 
03-22 07:54:00.998: INFO / DEBUG (1931): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000 
03-22 07:54:00.998: INFO / DEBUG (1931): r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 81893210 r3 00000000 
03-22 07:54:01.008: INFO / DEBUG (1931): r4 8189324c r5 818931d0 r6 00000000 r7 00000000 
03-22 07:54:01.008: INFO / DEBUG (1931): r8 00000200 r9 00000600 10 00000300 00000500 fp 
03-22 07:54:01.019: INFO / DEBUG (1931): ip 81350868 sp bef4c438 lr 8112cb3b pc 8112cb6c cpsr 80000030 
03-22 07:54:01.369: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 00 pc 0012cb6c / data / data / org.libsdl.app / lib / libtest.so 
03-22 07:54:01.369: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 01 pc 0012db46 / data / data / org.libsdl.app / lib / libtest.so 
03-22 07:54:01.379: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 02 pc 0013052e / data / data / org.libsdl.app / lib / libtest.so 
03-22 07:54:01.379: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 03 pc 00132142 / data / data / org.libsdl.app / lib / libtest.so 
03-22 07:54:01.389: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 04 pc 001a2836 / data / data / org.libsdl.app / lib / libtest.so 
03-22 07:54:01.399: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 05 pc 00024ee6 / data / data / org.libsdl.app / lib / libtest.so 
03-22 07:54:01.399: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 06 pc 00013974 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.409: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 07 pc 0003de3c / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.409: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 08 pc 00037216 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.419: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 09 pc 000432ec / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.419: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 10 pc 00018714 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.439: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 11 pc 0001e8c4 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.439: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 12 pc 0001d790 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.439: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 13 pc 0005408e / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.449: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 14 pc 0005bde2 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.449: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 15 pc 00018714 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.459: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 16 pc 0001e8c4 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.469: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 17 pc 0001d790 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.469: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 18 pc 00053eec / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.479: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 19 pc 0004072c / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.479: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 20 pc 00034454 / system / lib / libdvm.so 
03-22 07:54:01.489: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 21 pc 0002c930 / system / lib / libandroid_runtime.so 
03-22 07:54:01.489: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 22 pc 0002d85c / system / lib / libandroid_runtime.so 
03-22 07:54:01.499: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 23 pc 00008c86 / system / bin / app_process 
03-22 07:54:01.519: INFO / DEBUG (31): # 24 pc 0000d362 / system / lib / libc.so

Can I use avcodec_decode_audio2? 
I have in recent days has reached the following code:

```
AVFormatContext * pFormatCtx; 
int i, videoStream, audioStream; 
AVCodecContext * pCodecCtx; 
AVCodec * pCodec; 
AVFrame * pFrame; 
AVPacket packet; 
int frameFinished; 
float aspect_ratio; 

AVCodecContext * aCodecCtx; 
AVCodec * aCodec; 


AVCodecContext * c = NULL; 
int out_size, len; 
int16_t * audio_buf; 
uint8_t * outbuf; 
uint8_t inbuf [AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE]; 



av_register_all (); 

char * str = (* env) -> GetStringUTFChars (env, argv, 0); 


if (av_open_input_file (& pFormatCtx, str, NULL, 0, NULL)! = 0) 
return -150; 


if (av_find_stream_info (pFormatCtx)  nb_streams; i + +) { 

if (pFormatCtx-> streams [i] -> codec-> codec_type == CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO & & videoStream  streams [i] -> codec-> codec_type == CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO & & audioStream  streams [audioStream] -> codec; 



aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder (aCodecCtx-> codec_id); 
if (! aCodec) { 
fprintf (stderr, "Unsupported codec! \ n"); 
return -45; 
} 

avcodec_open (aCodecCtx, aCodec); 
c = avcodec_alloc_context (); 
packet_queue_init (& audioq); 
while (av_read_frame (pFormatCtx, & packet)> = 0) { 


if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) { 

} Else if (packet.stream_index == audioStream) { 

packet_queue_put (& audioq, & packet); 
int len1, data_size; 
data_size = 417; 

len1 = avcodec_decode_audio2 (aCodecCtx, (int16_t *) audio_buf, & data_size, 
packet.data, packet.size); 
return packet.size; 
} Else { 
av_free_packet (& packet); 
} 



} 



return 0;
```

In this case, when the avcodec_decode_audio2 I got -1. What I did wrong?

Note:
When I drove int data_size = 417; then DEBUG does not appear and the function returns -1, but when I drive a: int data_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 2; then vyskakievaet DEBUG in your function so in my own! How can this be solved?

EDIT2:
My new code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_main( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, int argc, jstring argv, jbyteArray array) {
      AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
      int             i, videoStream, audioStream;
      AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx;
      AVCodec         *pCodec;
      AVFrame         *pFrame;
      AVPacket        packet;
      int             frameFinished;
      float           aspect_ratio;

      AVCodecContext  *aCodecCtx;
      AVCodec         *aCodec;

      SDL_Overlay     *bmp;
      SDL_Surface     *screen;
      SDL_Rect        rect;
      SDL_Event       event;
      SDL_AudioSpec   wanted_spec, spec;
      AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
         int out_size, len;
         int16_t *audio_buf;
         uint8_t *outbuf;
         uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
         char *pAudioBuffer = (char *) av_malloc (AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 2);




      av_register_all();

      char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, argv, 0);


      if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, str, NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
        return -150; // Couldn't open file


      if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)nb_streams; i++) {
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO &&
           videoStream streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO &&
           audioStream streams[audioStream]->codec;



      aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(aCodecCtx->codec_id);
      if(!aCodec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -45;
      }

      avcodec_open(aCodecCtx, aCodec);
      c=avcodec_alloc_context();
      packet_queue_init(&audioq);
        while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>= 0) {
            if (aCodecCtx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                        int data_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 2;
                        int size=packet.size;
                        while(size > 0) {
                                int len = avcodec_decode_audio3(aCodecCtx, (int16_t *) pAudioBuffer, &data_size, &packet);

                                jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
                                memcpy(bytes, (int16_t *) pAudioBuffer, size);
                                (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bytes, 0);


                                size = packet.size-len;
                                }
            }

     }










 return 5;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why do you use "size" in memcpy, and not len?
As I understand we copy from "pAudioBuffer" to "bytes" with length "size". But size is the avpacket size, while pAudioBuffer has decoded data, which has length "len". Is that correct? (I'm not C professional - trying to learn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use audiotrack class to do the work for you. You can do something like this.

JAVA side.

```
            AudioTrack track;

            int bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


            track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            track.play(); 

            while(true){
            readBufferFromNative(); //update buffer from native code

                    ....................
                    ....................
                    }
```

On native Side : You need to read the frames and convert them into raw pcm format first and then start filling the audio buffer continuously. When the buffer is full, it will automatically play.

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_ffmpeg_Main_jniMainEntry(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring input) {

    const char * pszFileName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, input, 0);
    AVFormatContext * m_fc;
    int err;
    AVPacket pkt;
    char * pAudioBuffer = (char *) av_malloc (AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 2);
    int i;

    avcodec_register_all ();
    avdevice_register_all ();
    av_register_all ();

    err = av_open_input_file(&m_fc, pszFileName, 0, 0, 0);
    err = av_find_stream_info(m_fc);
    for(i = 0; i<m_fc->nb_streams; i++) {
    if((m_fc->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) || (m_fc->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)) {
    AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_fc->streams[i]->codec->codec_id);

    if (codec == 0)
            continue;
    err = avcodec_open(m_fc->streams[i]->codec, codec);
    if (err <0)
            continue;
    }
 }
    while (av_read_frame(m_fc, &pkt)>= 0) {
            if (m_fc-> streams[pkt.stream_index]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                    int data_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 2;
                    int size=pkt->size;
                    while(size > 0) {
                            int len = avcodec_decode_audio3(m_fc->streams[pkt.stream_index]->codec, (int16_t *) pAudioBuffer, &data_size, &pkt);
                            LOGD("data_size %d len %d", data_size, len);
                            size = pkt->size-len;
                            }
            }
 }
```

}

Comment: I updated the question. Please do take a look again. There is a problem.

Comment: I have edited the code above little bit and also I have tried on my droid, avcodec_decode_audio3 always returns the bytes used by it and always a positive value. I don't have any problem with the above code. Try changing mallocs to av_malloc. Sometimes this will do.

Comment: Your code I have not compiled (did not find a function avdevice_register_all), but I upgraded my code and now returns something that is necessary. The question is: what to do with the buffers that I received? I understand - it should be transferred Java program. But how? I hope it's not hard:) 
P.S. Can I contact you via email? Therefore, if not too difficult, it might help somewhere else.

Comment: By the way here it is:
while (true) makes me:
03-22 17:54:24.916: WARN / ActivityManager (59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-22 17:54:26.387: WARN / ActivityManager (1959): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord {44f04510 org.libsdl.app / .SDLActivity}

What to do?

Comment: That's a very simple JNI question. Go through some JNI basics, It's very easy to update a buffer. Just pass a byte array to C code and use setbytearrayregion function to update it or return a byte array to JAVA.

Comment: That is clear. but that's what I wrote:
jbyte * m;
jbyteArray jb;
jb = (* env) -> NewByteArray (env, packet.size);
(* env) -> SetByteArrayRegion (env, jb, 0,
packet.size, (jbyte *) m);

return jb;
Is this true? I'm not experienced in jni, so if it's easy, please: help me with this. Ie I do not understand how I'm going to return something in the stream and it's all written in the AudioTrack.

Comment: I do not quite understand how to update it. And whether we should produce: track.write? If necessary, how to receive these bytes and write them in AudioTrack in your array (while (true))?

Comment: When you use SetByteArrayRegion, you don't need to return it again. It is already updated. If you are still getting problems with your code, Ask a new question with your JNI code.

Comment: Ie no track.write should not? Okay, I'll try.

Comment: To update the array, I realized that it is necessary so to do:
byte [] storeData = new byte [Size];
updateFromNative (storeData);

And then this storeData update in the program. So? Q: How do I know the size? How do I upgrade? If it is not difficult to write, please:.

Comment: pass the size also. That is updateFromeNative(stroeData, size). Instead of setByteArrayRegion, Use memcpy with getByteArrayElements and ReleaseByteArrayElements

Comment: So how do I take a size and what stroeData?

P.S. Try these two functions that you wrote. Thank you.

Comment: You should obtain size from audiotrack.getminbuffsize() function. byte [] storeData

Comment: I've written in java:

`byte [] bytes = new byte [bufSize];

         track.write (bytes, 0, bufSize);

         main (2, "/ sdcard/muzika_iz_reklami_bmw_5_series_-_bmw_5_series.mp3", bytes);`

And in the JNI:

`jbyte * bytes = (* env) -> GetByteArrayElements (env, array, NULL);
memcpy (bytes, (int16_t *) pAudioBuffer, size);
(* env) -> ReleaseByteArrayElements (env, array, bytes, 0);`

There are no errors, but the music either. What am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that decoding data is proper? Check that may be problem

Comment: some do not understood. Ie I have the correct code? so then what could be the problem?
P.S. decode function returns the normal length ...

Comment: I've updated the text of the question and posted there is my code. Look. In what may be the problem?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Just curious what was causing problem on your code.

Comment: Unfortunately not decided ... Do you have a working example? (complete with output buffer through AudioTrack?

Answer (score 0):

I could not post a comment, so am posting this as an answer.

I'm also trying to do play aac audio using ffmpeg but have a lot of questions on how to get it working.

I tried using http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ as a reference, but the author of the code is not using avcodec_decode_audio3 for decoding. The playback through AudioTrack stutters a lot and I assume that the buffer is not getting filled by the decoder fast enough for the audiotrack to play.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Once again, sorry for posting this as a answer.

Comment: On what device you are testing it? It is damn slow on emulator. I tried the same on droid, it is good. Let me know if you  are not trying on emulator.

Comment: I've tested this on Droid and HTC Hero. The playback is the same across both.