# Audio playing back at the wrong speed using FFmpeg on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, decode, audio-player

General problem in the following:
I decode the audio as follows:

```
ReSampleContext* rsc = av_audio_resample_init(
        1, aCodecCtx->channels,
        aCodecCtx->sample_rate, aCodecCtx->sample_rate,
        av_get_sample_fmt("u8"), aCodecCtx->sample_fmt,
        16, 10, 0, 1);

while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>= 0) {
    if (aCodecCtx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        int data_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 2;
        int size=packet.size;
        int decoded = 0;

         while(size > 0) {
             int len = avcodec_decode_audio3(aCodecCtx, pAudioBuffer, 
                 &data_size, &packet);

             //Сonvert audio to sample 8bit
             out_size = audio_resample(rsc, outBuffer, pAudioBuffer, len);

             jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);

             memcpy(bytes, outBuffer, out_size);
             (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bytes, 0);
             (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, mid, array, out_size, number);

             size -= len;
             number++;
         }
     }
 }
```

Next release it AudioTrack. After that, I hear that song that was necessary, but with noise and speed of 2 times larger. In what may be the problem?

UPDATE:
This is Java code:

```
public static AudioTrack track;
public static byte[] bytes;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int bufSize = 2048;
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, 
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, bufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM); 

    bytes = new byte[bufSize];
    Thread mAudioThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int res = main(2, "/sdcard/muzika_iz_reklami_bmw_5_series_-_bmw_5_series.mp3", bytes);
            System.out.println(res);
        } 
    });
    mAudioThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    mAudioThread.start(); 
}

private static void play(byte[] play, int length, int p) {
    if (p==0){
        track.play();
    }
    track.write(play, 0, length); 
}
```

Comment: accept answers to your previous questions; you asked 8 questions, but accepted only 1; it's in your profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem of sampling rate mismatch. May be you are creating audioTrack with a lesser sampler rate compared to actual rate.

It could be also a problem with the AudioTrack channel configuration, as **Matthew** mentioned.

May be you should try something like I have answered in this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367595/how-to-decode-audio-via-ffmpeg-in-android/5386100#5386100)**.

Because the way you are interacting with JNI from Java, I am not sure, whether that will work. I have little knowledge about JNI. But my code works with me and which is what I am currently using with my app.

Comment: I ask in the C sample rate 44100 and Audiotrack put the same. Maybe there are other problems?

Comment: Is the sampling rate of audio in the file is same as 44100? FFmpeg will give you the sampling rate of the file to be played. Use the same. In other way, there is a tool called mediainfo, which will give you  the codec and other details of the file. See whether it is correct.

Comment: aCodecCtx-> sample_rate returns me 44,100! How can it be wrong samplerate?

Comment: This may be a problem with the transfer of the buffer? Today I'll post the code AudioTrack. Take a look

Comment: Answer updated. May be you should try a different approach for JNI interaction. I am not sure what went wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your `AudioTrack` is expecting stereo data but you are sending it mono. You could try setting your `AudioTrack` channel configuration to [CHANNEL_OUT_MONO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html#CHANNEL_OUT_MONO).

Comment: I use CHANELL_OUT_MONO, but it does not help